# Rails: Is it possible to Trigger a mailer method with a link_to or button_to method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, link-to, button-to

I'm trying to create an admin Tool where the admins can send emails that are already there with a button.

I have a `class FamilyMailer < ActionMailer::Base`  with this method `birthdaymailer`

Is there a way for me to trigger this from the view ?

I have seen a lot of answers on StackOverFlow, but it doesn't really work.

The closest conclusion I have came across is that the Mailer gets triggered this way `FamilyMailer.birthdaymailer` in the view and create a return to main page.

I was wondering if there would be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure!

Say you've got a mailer, called UserMailer.

Set up your controller action:

```
# my_controller.rb

def send_mail
  @parameters = Model.get_parameters
  UserMailer.name_of_action(@parameters).deliver
end
```

Set up your route:

```
get send_mail, to: 'my_controller#send_mail', as: :send_mail
```

Then make your link!

```
link_to 'Send mail', send_mail_path, class: "big-button"
```

Voila.

Comment: if you want this to be semi silent, you can (following the above) call the endpoint with AJAX or add a redirect at the end of the method to put you back on the page you started on.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar :)! BUT I will still choose it as an answer, because I still didn't know this would be possible! Thanks @Steel